# need to recover trados project with translation

Tags: translation, language-translation, xliff

I was working on a language translation project in trados on a virtual machine.  Half of the work was done and the translated words were exported into a Word docx file.  Upon restarting the virtul machine, the project file appears to have been corrupted as trados shows no signs that the project was worked on.  When I manually open the sdlproj (trados project) file, trados cannot open the file mentioning the following:

`: An error occured whilst trying to determine the file version`

I have tried creating a new project and used pre-translate using batch tasks but that did not seem to have imported the previously translated document.  I need to figure out how to recover my project so that I can recover the translated document (so I do not have to redo the work) as well as recover the translation memory for trados.  The translation memory folder is present inside the original project folder.  I would really appreciate any suggestion to further troubleshoot and fix this issue.  I have tried their support desk but they do not appear to be available today.  Two solutions I observed from their forum suggested:

1. save the project file with a zip extension, extract the contents and then open the sdlxiff file from there
2. recreate the project and use pre-translate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, I was able to open the sdlxiff file from the translated language directory.  This opened the project with the text that had previously been translated.  I am not certain whether I need to remove the sdlproj file or simply save the project hoping that it will overwrite the corrupted file.  In either case, I will update this post once I get an answer to that.